# What are the CUDA variables mean?

Tags: cuda, gpu

What are the CUDA variables mean?

```
Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
Maximum sizes of each dimension of a block:    1024 x 1024 x 64
Maximum sizes of each dimension of a grid:     2147483647 x 65535 x 65535
```

For example, `Maximum sizes of each dimension of a grid,` does it mean there're 2147483647 grids. And each grid contains 65535 blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, those are the maximal HW limits that you can use. You have maximum dim of block 1024x1024x64, but the limit for thread per block is 1024, so you can use block dimension 1024x1x1 or 32x32x1 etc. You can't have more, but of course, you can use less.

Generally, it is up to you, how you set your grid a block dimensions (within the limits), it depends on what you need. The very basic hierarchy is, that you have a grid of blocks. Each block contains threads. So if you have grid dimensions 2x2x2 and block dimensions 16x1x1, there are 8 blocks and each block has 16 threads, so there are 128 threads running.

CUDA has a great documentation, so I suggest you start [there.](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-hierarchy)